# Working with Dates in Spark

Tags: date, apache-spark, filtering, rdd

I have a requirement where a CSV file is to be parsed, identify the records between the specific dates and find total and average sales for each sales person per ProductCategory in that duration. Below is the CSV file structure:

SalesPersonId,SalesPersonName,SaleDate,SaleAmount,ProductCategory

Please help in resolving this query. Looking for solution in Scala

What I tried:

Used the SimpleDateFormat as mentioned below:
val format = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy")
and created an RDD with the below piece of code:
val onlyHouseLoan = readFile.map(line => (line.split(",")(0), line.split(",")(2), line.split(",")(3).toLong, **format.parse(line.split(",")(4).toString())**))

However, I tried using the Calendar on top of the highlighted expression but getting error that NumberformatExpression.

Comment: Did you even try to write anything?

Comment: You should really try harder when asking a question if you expect someone to reply.

Comment: Obviously I tried and then only I had asked. End of the day it is me who should complete and deliver. I don't want to post work that I get into forums and enjoy live. Also, I am the community contributor to Microsoft technologies. I do help resolving issues wherever I have experience. Hope this helps you understand. Note that I would have shared what I tried if that is logical enough to be posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So by just creating a quick rdd in the format of the csv-file you describe

```
val list = sc.parallelize(List(("1","Timothy","04/02/2015","100","TV"), ("1","Timothy","04/03/2015","10","Book"), ("1","Timothy","04/03/2015","20","Book"), ("1","Timothy","04/05/2015","10","Book"),("2","Ursula","04/02/2015","100","TV")))
```

And then running

```
import java.time.LocalDate
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

val startDate = LocalDate.of(2015,1,4)
val endDate = LocalDate.of(2015,4,5)

val result = list
    .filter{case(_,_,date,_,_) => {
         val localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"))
         localDate.isAfter(startDate) && localDate.isBefore(endDate)}}
    .map{case(id, _, _, amount, category) => ((id, category), (amount.toDouble, 1))} 
    .reduceByKey((v1, v2) => (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2)) 
    .map{case((id, category),(total, sales)) => (id, List((category, total, total/sales)))} 
    .reduceByKey(_ ++ _)
```

will give you

```
(1,List((Book,30.0,15.0), (TV,100.0,100.0)))
(2,List((TV,100.0,100.0)))
```

in the format of (SalesPersonId, [(ProductCategory,TotalSaleAmount, AvgSaleAmount)]. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Hi Glennie - Thank you very much for your response. I am using your approach to achieve what  I needed. I will update you soon.

Comment: BTW, I didn't see your edit until after my answer, but you can also parse the date initially if you want with `val onlyHouseLoan = readFile.map(line => {
      val subStrings = line.split(",")
      (subStrings(0), subStrings(2), subStrings(3).toLong, LocalDate.parse(subStrings(4),DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy")))
    })`

Comment: Hi Glennie, Thanks for your suggestion on the date part, I will try that. However, below is the code which I could write based on your approach:   <pre>   val onlyHouseLoan = readFile.map(line => (line.split(",")(2), line.split(",")(3).toLong, getYearFromDate(line.split(",")(4).toString()))).filter(_._1 == "house") //filtering for housing loan
.filter{case(_,_,year) => {(year >= 1960 && year <= 1970)}} //between specified years.map{case (loantype, loanamount,_ ) => (loantype, (loanamount, 1))}.reduceByKey((v1, v2) => (v1._1 + v2._1, v1._2 + v2._2)) <code>. Written based on your approach.

Comment: However, one more thing which is remaining, that is to calculate average. I got the loan type as "housing", total loan amount and the record count. I am unable to write expression to calculate average. Please suggest to complete that. Secondly, I am a beginner and learning spark. Can you please provide pointers which help me in writing/adopting the coding style/pattern that you have used. The problem breaking into different pieces and using the feature set. Any blogs/help links that make me think through from an approach perspective. That would really help. Thanks once again.

Comment: To calculate and include the average for each category you simply need to add a final `.mapValues{case(totalLoanAmount, recordCount) => (totalLoanAmount, totalLoanAmount.toDouble/recordCount)}`. Note that I explicitly cast totalLoanAmount to a Double, because either the loanAmount or the recordCount needs to be of type Double to get the result in Double. From your code it seems that loanAmount is of type Long.

Comment: Hi Glennie, It worked. Thanks a ton. Request you to provide me some pointers from where I can get good grip on this way of breaking the problem and develop the code. That would be a great help for me.

Comment: Hi Phaneendra, I have to say that personally I have had to go through a lot of trial-and-error, simply because Spark is new and fast developing so the documentation is frequently outdated. That said, I would point you to http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html and https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/, which I found quite good. As to getting into the way of breaking the problem down, I don't know how familiar you are with functional programming, but it really is essential that you understand that way of thinking, before tackling Spark :)